# Requirements coverage using pytest

Tags: pytest

We use LabGrid for our testing, which is based on pytest. I would like to do some requirements coverage measuring. All the searches on covertage for pytest, ends up in line coverage for python and that is not what I want.
Actually I'm not testing python code at all, but remotely testing features on an embedded target.

Now my idea was to create a marker for each test function with an URL to a requirement (eg in Jira). Now when a requirement is identified, then first thing to do is to add an empty test case in the pytest, and mark it as skipped (or some not tested).

After running the test, a report could be generated, telling the total coverage, with links. This would require the information being dumped into the junit.xml file.

In this way I get a tight link between the test and the requirement, bound in the test code.

Now anybody knows of some markers which could help do this. Or even some projects which has gotten a similar idea.

Answer (score 2):

we are using a marker which we create by ourselves:

pytest.mark.reqcov(JIRA-123)

Afterwards we analyzing the test run with self written script.
Using some pytest hooks, collecting the marker, checking JIRA via python api and creating metrics out of it (we are using Testspace).
Not found a way to add this marker to junit report.

Link to JIRA can be done in different ways,

1. using SPHINX docu and link the Jira id automatically from test
   case description to Jira
2. use the python script, which analyze the requirements coverage
   and create a link to Jira.

hope that helps